# Possible Known Issue with Eclipse Layout Builder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, eclipse-adt

I'm building a layout within Eclipse for Android using the `RelativeLayout`. I lay down a simple stack of buttons one on top of each other. For some reason the button snaps to the first button position even though I clearly place it down on the last stack of buttons. I try everything to move it to the right position eventually I just let the layout builder stick it to the bottom of the screen edge.

When I try this view inside the app, the last button is magically snapped to some random spot usually near the top. Obviously incorrect. As a hunch I tried it again but I left it alone this time, when I laid the last button down again ( which within Eclipse Layout builder its snapped to the first elements position for some crazy reason). Surprisingly within the app itself it appears in the proper location. So this must be a bug with the Layout builder itself.

It looks horrible in Layout builder (almost unusable) and the position of UI elements totally wrong, is this some known bug with Layout Builder + Android or do I need some update or new SDK or something?

Comment: I recommend you get accustomed to building your `layout`s using the xml tab and create them manually. IMHO, you get more control over them and you learn more about the `View hierarchy` this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reported complaints about the ADK Editor for Eclipse, but one alternative is to try DroidDraw

http://www.droiddraw.org/

The preference of some Android developers is to directly modify the XML. This often provides more flexibility as you can see the exact rules that are defined for your UI.

If you are looking at just stacking `Button`s on top of each other, you may want to consider a `LinearLayout`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

This is a layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout every "view" is positioned relative to something else. It would help you to understand better if you look at the xml. You will see what each item is aligned on. It is difficult to get this layout right as you see especially when you design in eclipse and run on an avd or real device. Consider placing a linear layout inside the relative layout and your buttons in that. This way your button group is together in a row or column and next to this you could have text or something.hard to explain but group like things together and nest layout inside other layouts.frame layout only one item is viewable at a time,like pages in a book or slide images. I hope I explained this good. I have no idea why you would do buttons that way.absolute layout is x,y positions where you put it is where it stays. Like that's gonna work. Try a different screen density and things are bunched up in the corner.like I said the key is nesting the layouts